# Unable to deploy django project on windows server using mod_wsgi and wamp

Tags: python, django, wamp, mod-wsgi

Instead of my django project running and showing my landing page. I'm only able to view my project files on localhost. The project runs fine on development when using `python manage.py runserver` but does not work with mod_wsgi and wamp.

in my wamp's apache httpd.conf file, I've added:

```
ServerName localhost:8000
Listen localhost:8000
Listen [::0]:80
.
.
Include "conf/extra/httpd-vhosts.conf"
.
.
# Django Project
LoadFile "c:/python3.6/python36.dll"
LoadModule wsgi_module "c:/python3.6/lib/site-packages/mod_wsgi/server/mod_wsgi.cp36-win_amd64.pyd"
WSGIPythonHome "c:/python3.6"
WSGIPythonPath "C:/irfan/metatrader_api/mt5"
```

in my httpd-vhost.conf, I have :

```
#
WSGIPythonPath "C:/irfan/metatrader_api/mt5"

<VirtualHost *:8000>
    WSGIPassAuthorization On
    ErrorLog "logs/mt5.error.log"
    CustomLog "logs/mt5.access.log" combined
    DocumentRoot "c:/irfan/metatrader_api/mt5/mt5"
    WSGIScriptAlias /  "C:\irfan\metatrader_api\mt5\mt5\wsgi_windows.py"
    <Directory  "c:\irfan\metatrader_api\mt5\mt5">
        <Files wsgi_windows.py>
            Require all granted
        </Files>
    </Directory>
</VirtualHost>

WSGIApplicationGroup %{GLOBAL}
```

in wsgi_windows.py, I have

```
activate_this = "C:/irfan/irfan/Scripts/activate_this.py"
# execfile(activate_this, dict(__file__=activate_this))
exec(open(activate_this).read(),dict(__file__=activate_this))

import os
import sys
import site

# Add the site-packages of the chosen virtualenv to work with
site.addsitedir("C:/irfan/irfan/Lib/site-packages")[![enter image description here][1]][1]

# Add the app's directory to the PYTHONPATH
sys.path.append('C:/irfan/metatrader_api/mt5')
sys.path.append('C:/irfan/metatrader_api/mt5/mt5')

os.environ['DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE'] = 'mt5.settings'
os.environ.setdefault("DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE", "mt5.settings")

from django.core.wsgi import get_wsgi_application
application = get_wsgi_application()
```